# Run MTProxy remotely by PHP exec on Windows server

Tags: php, node.js, cmd, windows-server, mtproto

I installed PM2 and node.js on the Windows server to run [JSMTProxy-master](https://github.com/FreedomPrevails/JSMTProxy) script.

The command for the run proxy is: (pm2 start "JSMTProxy-master\mtproxy.js" -i max) and it executed successfully in the CMD window with no problem.

Now I want to execute this command by PHP and exec.

I tried this:

```
exec ('pm2 start "JSMTProxy-master\mtproxy.js" -i max');
```

Or this: (just showed up cmd.exe in taskmgr)

```
exec ('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START "pm2 start c:\mypath\JSMTProxy-master\mtproxy.js -i max"');
```

Or this:

```
exec ('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START "JSMTProxy-master\mtp-run.bat"');
```

These don't work and nothing happens. no error, no process showed up in taskmgr.

How is it supposed to be to run by exec?

Note. I have PHP installed and working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different ways many times, Finally i found the problem.
"PM2" doesn't execute under PHP exexc. It has to be with full path of exe files.

I changed my command as below and it worked:

```
shell_exec('C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\pm2.cmd start "C:\mypath\JSMTProxy-master\mtproxy.js" -i max')
```